# How to access KMMShared MutableStateFlow object in Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, swiftui, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KmmShared singleton class with a MutableStateFlow which works fine with Android. I need to know the best way to access this Singleton class and it's MutableStateFlow variable with updates in SwiftUI application.

```
class MySingeltonClass {
    private val _selectedType: MutableStateFlow<MyEnum> = MutableStateFlow(getUserPrefsType())
    var selectedType = _selectedType.asStateFlow()

    private fun getUserPrefsType() : MyEnum {
        // Get Enum from DB
    }

    fun setType(scheme: MyEnum) {
        // Set Enum in DB
        _selectedType.value = scheme
    }

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: MySingeltonClass
        fun getInstance(): MySingeltonClass {
            if (!this::instance.isInitialized) {
                instance = MySingeltonClass()
            }
            return instance
        }

    }
}

enum class MyEnum {
    TYPEA, TYPEB, TYPEC;
}
```

If I can have a `MySingeltonWrapperClass` with a `@Published var selectedType` or a `@ObservedObject private var selectedType` is something that I'm trying to achieve in Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's kinda tricky topic. The main problems with `Flow` / `StateFlow` in SwiftUI applications lay in Kotlin <-> Swift interoperability. Because it has several limitations:

- interoperability [doesn't work on Generic Interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#limitations)
- we need to launch flow in specific `CoroutineScope` to be able to cancel job

Good articles to understand better: [one](https://betterprogramming.pub/kotlin-suspending-functions-as-swift-async-await-with-adapter-pattern-a79aacaa5b1c), [two](https://dev.to/ttypic/kmm-writing-kotlin-api-for-swift-7-things-you-need-to-know-4io6)

There are several workarounds available:

#### 1. Wrap `Flow` in Kotlin `class`. Great example of this technique you can find in the [official KMM sample repo](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-production-sample).

At first, [author introduces new class](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-production-sample/blob/master/shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/com/github/jetbrains/rssreader/core/CFlow.kt) `CFlow`:

```kotlin
fun interface Closeable {
    fun close()
}

class CFlow<T: Any> internal constructor(private val origin: Flow<T>) : Flow<T> by origin {
    fun watch(block: (T) -> Unit): Closeable {
        val job = Job()

        onEach {
            block(it)
        }.launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job))

        return Closeable { job.cancel() }
    }
}

internal fun <T: Any> Flow<T>.wrap(): CFlow<T> = CFlow(this)
```

Then [uses it in SwiftUI](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-production-sample/blob/master/iosApp/iosApp/RSSApp.swift#L30):

```swift
class ObservableFeedStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var state: FeedState =  FeedState(progress: false, feeds: [], selectedFeed: nil)
    
    var stateWatcher : Closeable?

    init(store: FeedStore) {
        stateWatcher = self.store.watchState().watch { [weak self] state in
            self?.state = state
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        stateWatcher?.close()
    }
}
```

### 2. Use special libraries, e.g. [KMP-NativeCoroutines](https://github.com/rickclephas/KMP-NativeCoroutines).

When you setup this library you can create Swift `AnyPublisher` for your Kotlin `Flow` / `StateFlow`:

```swift
let publisher = createPublisher(for: yourFlow)
```

#### 3. Don't use `Flow`/ `StateFlow`. You can use simple alternative for it. Take a look at [Decompose project](https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose) and it's `Value` [class](https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose/blob/master/decompose/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/arkivanov/decompose/value/Value.kt).

```kotlin
abstract class Value<out T : Any> {
    abstract val value: T
    abstract fun subscribe(observer: (T) -> Unit)
    abstract fun unsubscribe(observer: (T) -> Unit)
}
```

You can still pretty easy use it in your Compose Application to get `State`, [sample from Decompose](https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose/blob/master/extensions-compose-jetpack/src/main/java/com/arkivanov/decompose/extensions/compose/jetpack/SubscribeAsState.kt):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T : Any> Value<T>.subscribeAsState(policy: SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> = structuralEqualityPolicy()): State<T> {
    val state = remember(this, policy) { mutableStateOf(value, policy) }

    DisposableEffect(this) {
        val observer: (T) -> Unit = { state.value = it }

        subscribe(observer)

        onDispose {
            unsubscribe(observer)
        }
    }

    return state
}
```

and in SwiftUI you can use, `ObservableValue` [helper from Decompose](https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose/blob/master/sample/app-ios/app-ios/DecomposeHelpers/ObservableValue.swift):

```swift
public class ObservableValue<T : AnyObject> : ObservableObject {
    private let observableValue: Value<T>

    @Published
    var value: T

    private var observer: ((T) -> Void)?
    
    init(_ value: Value<T>) {
        observableValue = value
        self.value = observableValue.value
        observer = { [weak self] value in self?.value = value }
        observableValue.subscribe(observer: observer!)
    }

    deinit {
        observableValue.unsubscribe(observer: self.observer!)
    }
}
```